# upgrading mongodb from 3.6 to 4.0

Tags: installation, apt, mongodb, upgrade

I followed all the instructions on [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), and aft apt-get it says

```
mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.0.10).
```

but when i start it again and run mongod --version, it still says

```
db version v3.6.13
```

How do I switch to the new version?

results from `sudo systemctl status mongodb.service`

> ● mongodb.service
>   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: Where did the other MongoDB installation come from?

Comment: im not sure, someone installed it for me

Comment: You have two versions of `mongodb` installed and version 3.6.13 is the first one in your PATH hence it being referenced in your second output. The only one installed by `apt` is `4.0.10` which is why it specifies that it's already the latest version. Did you or someone else build another one from source on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it worked after I ran

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.10
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y --fix-missing --allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check what mongodb service is running. Try the command: `sudo systemctl status mongodb.service`. It will show you which mongodb is running.

Comment: ran that and added the result to the post, not sure what it means though

Answer (score 0):

It could happen that only `mongodb-org` package was updated.
To check that you can run:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep mongodb
```

**All steps for upgrading 3.6 => 4.0**

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Important part:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.14 mongodb-org-server=4.0.14 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.14 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.14 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.14
```

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

```
mongo -version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.14
...
```

```
mongod -version
db version v4.0.14
...
```

Btw, to check what's the latest patch version available run:

```
apt policy mongodb-org
```

That worked for me, I hope it will for you too :)